# Wrong child class function being called due to signature difference

Tags: c++, c++98

I have an event emitter that emits events and event handlers that handle events. I can extend the `Event` object to make different events like `AlarmEvent`, and the `EventHandler` object to make `AlarmEventHandler`. `EventHandler` has a function `HandleEvent(Event &event)`. This causes a problem for child classes that may have `HandleEvent(AlarmEvent &event)` methods. Obviously these are two different functions so there is no overriding taking place here. I need instead for `HandleEvent` to be overridden by the child class.

I fully understand the problem is that each `EventHandler` has a different `HandleEvent` signature so the `EventEmitter` will always handle events with the base `EventHandler::HandleEvent`. I thought by using `Event &event` as a paremeter to `EventEmitter::Emit` it would know what kind of `Event` it was dealing with and choose the correct method.

How can I have my `EventEmitter` call `AlarmEventHandler::HandleEvent` instead of the base method `EventHandler::HandleEvent` ?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// event types
class Event {};
class AlarmEvent : public Event {};

// event handler
class EventHandler {
    public:
        virtual void HandleEvent(Event event);
};
void EventHandler::HandleEvent(Event event){
    std::cout << "Handle event " << std::endl;   
}

// alarm event handler
class AlarmEventHandler : public EventHandler {
    public:
        void HandleEvent(AlarmEvent event);  
};
void AlarmEventHandler::HandleEvent(AlarmEvent event){
    std::cout << "Handle alarm event " << std::endl;   
}

// event emitter
class Emitter {
    public:  
        std::vector<EventHandler*> handlers;
        void Emit(Event &event);
};
void Emitter::Emit(Event &event){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->handlers.size(); i++){
        this->handlers[i]->HandleEvent(event);   
    }
}

int main()
{
    AlarmEventHandler handler;
    AlarmEvent event;
    Emitter emitter;
    emitter.handlers.push_back(&handler);
    // problem:
    // Handle event printed instead of Handle alarm event
    emitter.Emit(event);
}
```

Comment: You can't have different functions with the same name in derived classes.  The base class function and derived class function are in different namespaces, so the compiler won't even consider them as overloads of each other.  The signature has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Um, what's the point of `virtual` then? I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: You use `virtual` if the child function has the same signature as the parent function and is meant to be called in its place. If the functions have the same name but different signatures, the normal signature resolution process gets bypassed because the child function "hides" the parent function. First the compiler looks up the function name, then tries to match the signature - if it finds the function in the child, it doesn't bother looking in the parent.

Comment: You may find the [`override` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) added in the C++11 Standard revision helpful in trapping functions that you want to override a base class but do not.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's why I said literally everything you said in my question!

Comment: But I think you're missing my main point - the mechanics of C++ make what you're asking for impossible. You can call the base class function, or you can call the child class function, but you can't make the compiler choose which one to call automatically.

Comment: I know.. that's why I asked here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)!

So your `AlarmEventHandler` could look like:

```
// alarm event handler
class AlarmEventHandler : public EventHandler {
    public:
        void HandleEvent(const Event &event); // Our polymorphic override
        void HandleEvent(AlarmEvent event);  // Our custom Alarm logic
};

void AlarmEventHandler::HandleEvent(const Event &event){
    try {
        HandleEvent(dynamic_cast<const AlarmEvent&>(event));
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "I can't handle things that aren't AlarmEvents!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void AlarmEventHandler::HandleEvent(const AlarmEvent &event){
    std::cout << "Handle alarm event " << std::endl;   
}
```

To do this though, you'll need `Event` to be a polymorphic class. So you make the destructor `virtual`:

```
class Event { 
    public: virtual ~Event() {} //Need this so Event is a polymorphic class
};
```

See it run here: https://ideone.com/KMkLfq

Comment: Ah, and what if I'm stuck in C++ 98 :(

Comment: @errno_44 the code I've posted in the ideone link all compiles and runs fine for me in C++98. Are you getting a specific error when trying to use the concepts from my example?

Comment: @scohe001 I'll need to test it out

Answer (score 3):

You are not overriding `HandleEvent()`, you are overloading it.

You need a pointer or reference to be able to take advantage of dynamic dispatch to not have to cast.

Comments inline:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// event types
class Event {
    public:
        virtual ~Event();                       // make base destructor virtual
};

Event::~Event() {}

class AlarmEvent : public Event {};

// event handler
class EventHandler {
    public:
        virtual void HandleEvent(Event& event);
        virtual ~EventHandler();                 // virtual base destructor
};

EventHandler::~EventHandler() {}

void EventHandler::HandleEvent(Event& event){
    std::cout << "Handle event " << std::endl;   
}

// alarm event handler
class AlarmEventHandler : public EventHandler {
    public:
        //void HandleEvent(AlarmEvent& event);  // overload, does not override
        void HandleEvent(Event& event);
};

void AlarmEventHandler::HandleEvent(Event& event){
    std::cout << "Handle alarm event " << std::endl;   
}

// event emitter
class Emitter {
    public:
        Emitter() : handlers() {}
        std::vector<EventHandler*> handlers;
        void Emit(Event &event);
};

void Emitter::Emit(Event& event) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->handlers.size(); i++){
        this->handlers[i]->HandleEvent(event);   
    }
}

int main() {
    AlarmEventHandler handler;
    AlarmEvent event;
    Emitter emitter;
    emitter.handlers.push_back(&handler);
    emitter.Emit(event);
}
```

Compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++98 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -pedantic -pedantic-errors
```

Output:

```
Handle alarm event
```

Comment: I like it. This is polymorphism done right. If I'm an event handler inheriting from `EventHandler`, I should be able to handle an `Event`. If I'm a special event, I should be able to do all of my special things through the interface `Event` has given me. Anything else (like my answer) gets extremely messy extremely quickly.

Comment: I do like this, but I don't like `EventHandler` not being able to be constructed on its own. Sometimes people will want to fire plain old `Events`. Should I make a useless abstract base class for these to inherit from?

Comment: ..Appreciate the efforts. It still cannot handle an `AlarmEvent`, however. Perhaps it really is impossible.

Comment: @errno_44 It's compiled with `c++98` and prints it ok for me: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ntzVqa)

Comment: Right, but `AlarmEventHandler` can only handle `Event`s. Ie if `AlarmEvent` had a property `std::string msg`, `AlarmEventHandler::HandleEvent` would not be able to print out `event.msg`.

Comment: @errno_44 Look at the output of the program. Doesn't it print `Handle alarm event ` for you too?

Comment: Yes. But suppose `AlarmEvent` had a method or something, like `AlarmEvent.GetAlarmCount()`. It cannot be called by `AlarmEventHandler::HandleEvent` because it thinks its just an `Event`.

Comment: @errno_44 For interface functions like `GetAlarmCount()`, you'll have to add `virtual` methods in your base classes that you override in your subclasses. If you want to call functions not present in all subclasses, you'll have to downcast.

Comment: @errno_44 If you need the handler to know the type of the event, you should probably not be using polymorphism to begin with. Templates could be a different approach that preserves types.

Comment: Yes, I think templates would work. I just find them super confusing and wouldn't know where to begin.